# Conditionally loading the template in a angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to load the template of directive only conditionally, for example-

```
.directive('truncate',["$window", function($window, $compile){
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'template/truncate.html',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
         var height = element[0].offsetHeight;
         var shouldBetruncated = height>200;
         if(shouldBetruncated){
           // want my template to load here, otherwise template is not loaded
         };
      }
   }
}])
.run(function ($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put('template/truncate.html',
            'template code'
        );
 })
```

Is there anyway to acheive this?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*This will solve you problem*/


link: ...
templateUrl: function() {
    if(shouldBetruncated) {
        return 'template/truncate.html';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

For more info, you can pass the template from html or generate based on conditions

Comment: templateUrl: 'template/truncate.html' , this is an object syntax, are you sure it can be used here as its not working

Comment: if condition should be outside the link function

Comment: But the catch is that my condition will be evaluated in link function only, so need to apply this from there

Comment: i have updated answer as per your requirement, just check it once

Comment: I am not clear, how will be shouldBetruncated variable available outside link function, or maybe I am reading the code wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
.directive('truncate',["$window", function($window, $compile){
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  templateUrl: 'template/truncate.html',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
     var height = element[0].offsetHeight;
     shouldBetruncated = height>200;
     if(shouldBetruncated){
        loadTemplate();
     };
// function loadTemplate -- begins
var loadTemplate = function ($templateCache) {
            $templateCache.put('template/truncate.html',
        'template code'
   );
        };
// -- ends

  }
```

}
}]);

Comment: directive is not able to find the template until loadTemplate function is run, so it throws an error

Comment: Can you create one plunkr link , so that It will helpful to solve the issue.